# OpenGL: How to implement Camera Rear View

Tags: c++, opengl, view, camera, light

I'm in the process of implementing a camera class in OpenGL. But I ran into a problem. I do not know how to correctly implement the rear view by changing the values ​​of eye, target, up for LookAt.
Can you help me?

Comment: simply invert the direction vector?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the direction vector by another vector with -1 on all the axes you want to invert.

```
glm::vec3 negative(-1.f, -1.f, -1.f);
direction = direction * negative;
```

Comment: but glm::LookAt() function only accepts eye, target, up. How can I be with this. (sorry, I'm new to OpenGL).

Comment: I am new to this as well, but In the lookat function the eye should be equal to the direction(from my example) plus the camera position.